# Isometric line tool for photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel

Is it possible in photoshop to adjust the line tool while holding SHIFT so it could create a 26 or 30 degrees line angle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. Not possible. Shift will only constrain to 45° angle increments.

Comment: So no posible way to make it easier in PS heh! :(

Comment: Nope. I'm not really certain why you'd even begin to use Photoshop for isometric drawing. Illustrator or any vector-based app is much better suited for it.

Comment: @Scott, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

"Isometric" pixel art, as per [Eboy](http://hello.eboy.com/eboy/) uses lines with a 2:1 horizontal:vertical ratio. As far as I am aware, these are constructed from copy-pasting pixels rather than using Photoshop's line tool - [here's a tutorial](http://gas13.ru/v3/tutorials/isometric_pixelart_tutorial_mathematics_of_isometrics.php).

This is a 26.66° angle (arctan (1/2)).